# Joomla works without my new ftp password, how that's possible?

Tags: administrator, configuration, account-password

I changed my database password and I have changed it in the configuration.php file but concerning my FTP password I can't find where I need to change it in Joomla.

The weird things is that my new ftp password is effective (I tested it with filezila) but somehow joomla can still connect to the ftp even though I haven't updated it anywhere in joomla. Actually I could not find it where I am supposed to change the ftp password. I have checked the configuration.php and the global configuration in the administrator.

1. Is this normal?
2. If it is, how can Joomla (3.3.1) retrieve the .CSS, .php, etc. files without having the ftp password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the FTP settings in Joomla, go to:

1. Joomla backend
2. Global Configuration
3. Select the **Server** tab.
4. Under **FTP Settings**, set "**Enable FTP**" to "**Yes**", which will then slide down the required options for you til fill in.

These settings only need to be added in if your server requires you to use FTP within Joomla. I was a little confused with your question so I will simply write a few facts down here.

You obviously already have an FTP account which I assume you've created in your hosting control panel. If you are adding files to your Joomla site via FTP and have changed the password for the account, you will not be able to connect, no if's or buts, it simply will not allow you to connect. It is quite possible that you have created a separate FTP account and are still connecting via the old account. If you wish to change the password, be sure to update the current account.

Maybe you are referring to an anonymous FTP account, not entirely sure.

Comment: Thanks Lodder! I don't thing I have created a separate FTP account because I can't connect via filezilla with the previous password and I have updated it via the OVH manager. In Global Configuration/Server/FTP Settings, "Enable FTP" is set to No. If I set it to yes, then all the fields are empty: is that normal?

Comment: Yesh I have been having FTP problems today but I think that's a different story. It depends what you're trying to do, if you simply want to move files from your computer to your Joomla site, then you do not need to enable the FTP in Joomla's Global Configuration. For this, all you only need to create a FTP account in your OVH Manager.

Comment: yes, I only want to move new .css and new .php from my computer to the ftp, or to edit the existing Joomla files. So the OVH manager is the one which allows Joomla to access to the ftp. That's confusing because for Joomla to access the phpmyadmin I have to set the new password in configuration.php

Comment: Well yes, if you update your database password, you need to update it in the configuration.php else Joomla won't be able to connect to the database. As for the FTP, in your case, Joomla has nothing to do with this. FTP account is created on OVH and you connect with the account details using something like Filezilla

Comment: OK, I understand now and then everything is normal. Thanks a lot Lodder for your help!